# Ember-data queryRecord does not update template

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

- Ember: 2.3.0
- Ember Data: 2.3.2

I'm working with the **DS.JSONAPIAdapter**

I can't update my template when fetching data with **queryRecord** although data is correctly loaded.

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.queryRecord('question', {
      id: params.id,
      //include: 'question.something,question.otherthing'
    });
  }
});
```

The template does update when fetching data with **findRecord**.

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.findRecord('question', params.id);
  }
});
```

If I do something like this:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {

    if (this.store.hasRecordForId('question', params.id)) {
      return this.store.peekRecord('question', params.id);
    }

    return this.store.queryRecord('question', {
      id: params.id
      // include: ''
    }).then(function(result){ return result; });
  }
});
```

The first time I go to the route, data is loaded but the template is not updated. Second time **peekRecord()** is used and template is updated.

How to update a template when queryRecord is used ?
Thanks.

Comment: Is your template assuming that model is a single instance, or an array thereof?

Comment: Yes a single instance. The template is just the following for testing purpose:

`<h1>{{model.name}}</h1>`

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found the solution.

My backend uses the json-api specifications.

When I use queryRecord() as above, the request hits:

> http:////api/questions?id=1&include=answers

and the data response is a collection:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to hit

> http:////api/questions/1/?include=answers

and it's a pain at this time, a hack would be:

```
export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend(DataAdapterMixin, {

    urlForFindRecord(id, modelName, snapshot) {
    let url = this._super(...arguments);
    let query = Ember.get(snapshot, 'adapterOptions.query');
    if (query) {
      url += '/?' + Ember.$.param(query); // assumes no query params are present already
    }
    return url;
  },
});


export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {

    return this.store.findRecord('question', params.id, {
      adapterOptions: {
        query: {
          include: 'answers',
          limit: 1
        }
      }
    });
  }
});
```